# How to flag first change in a variable value between years, per group?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Given a very large longitudinal dataset with different groups, I need to create a flag that indicates the first change in a certain variable (`code`) between years (`year`), per group (`id`). The `type` of observation within the same id-year just indicates different group members.

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)    
sample <- tibble(id = rep(1:3, each=6),
                     year = rep(2010:2012, 3, each=2),
                     type = (rep(1:2, 9)),
                     code = c("abc","abc","","","xyz","xyz", "","","lmn","","efg","efg","def","def","","klm","nop","nop"))
```

What I need is to flag the first change to `code` within a group, between years. Second changes do not matter. Missing codes (`""`) can be treated as `NA` but in any case should not affect `flag`. The following is the above tibble with a flag field as it should be:

```
# A tibble: 18 × 5
      id  year  type  code  flag
   <int> <int> <int> <chr> <dbl>
1      1  2010     1   abc     0
2      1  2010     2   abc     0
3      1  2011     1           0
4      1  2011     2           0
5      1  2012     1   xyz     1
6      1  2012     2   xyz     1
7      2  2010     1           0
8      2  2010     2           0
9      2  2011     1   lmn     0
10     2  2011     2           0
11     2  2012     1   efg     1
12     2  2012     2   efg     1
13     3  2010     1   def     0
14     3  2010     2   def     0
15     3  2011     1           1
16     3  2011     2   klm     1
17     3  2012     1   nop     1
18     3  2012     2   nop     1
```

I still have a looping mindset and I am trying to use vectorized dplyr to do what I need. 
Any input would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: thanks for pointing this out regarding the importance of `year`. The id's are arranged by year, as the ordering is important here, and also all `types` per `id` per `year` need to have the same flag. So, in the edited row 15 e code is `""` which would not warrant a change by itself, but since in the same year row 16 has a new `code`, both observations need to have their codes changed to 1.

Comment: You should possibly update your example to demonstrate the relevance of the year-column better since most answers don't take it into account

Comment: Years only matter in two ways - (1) it is an ordering mechanism, and (2) all flags for id i should be the same in any single year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible solution using the `dplyr`.  not sure its the cleanest way though

```
sample %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  #find first year per group where code exists
  mutate(first_year = min(year[code != ""])) %>% 
  #gather all codes from first year (does not assume code is constant within year)
  mutate(first_codes = list(code[year==first_year])) %>% 
  #if year is not first year & code not in first year codes & code not blank
  mutate(flag = as.numeric(year != first_year & !(code %in% unlist(first_codes)) & code != "")) %>% 
  #drop created columns
  select(-first_year, -first_codes) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 5
      id  year  type  code  flag
   <int> <int> <int> <chr> <dbl>
1      1  2010     1   abc     0
2      1  2010     2   abc     0
3      1  2011     1           0
4      1  2011     2           0
5      1  2012     1   xyz     1
6      1  2012     2   xyz     1
7      2  2010     1           0
8      2  2010     2           0
9      2  2011     1   lmn     0
10     2  2011     2           0
11     2  2012     1   efg     1
12     2  2012     2   efg     1
13     3  2010     1   def     0
14     3  2010     2   def     0
15     3  2011     1   klm     1
16     3  2011     2   klm     1
17     3  2012     1   nop     1
18     3  2012     2   nop     1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)[, flag :=0][code!="",  flag := {rl <- rleid(code)-1; cummax(rl*(rl < 2)) }, id]
sample
#    id year type code flag
# 1:  1 2010    1  abc    0
# 2:  1 2010    2  abc    0
# 3:  1 2011    1         0
# 4:  1 2011    2         0
# 5:  1 2012    1  xyz    1
# 6:  1 2012    2  xyz    1
# 7:  2 2010    1         0
# 8:  2 2010    2         0
# 9:  2 2011    1  lmn    0
#10:  2 2011    2         0
#11:  2 2012    1  efg    1
#12:  2 2012    2  efg    1
#13:  3 2010    1  def    0
#14:  3 2010    2  def    0
#15:  3 2011    1  klm    1
#16:  3 2011    2  klm    1
#17:  3 2012    1  nop    1
#18:  3 2012    2  nop    1
```

#### Update

If we need to include the 'year' as well,

```
setDT(sample)[, flag :=0][code!="",  flag := {rl <- rleid(code, year)-1
                   cummax(rl*(rl < 2)) }, id]
```

Comment: +1 because it works (although I have no idea why - guess I need to learn data.table). Does it cause problems to change the resulting data.table into a data.frame or a tibble?

Comment: You're not using the `year` column which seems relevant from OP description

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Based on the comments, I guess the OP wants it arranged.  The example is already arranged, but it can be done with `order(year)` on the `i`

Comment: Well, I have a different understanding of the question - I think they only want to flag it when there is a year change and a new code. Hence, it's not simply about ordering the data.

Comment: @docendodiscimus  In that case, use `rleid` on `year` as well `setDT(sample)[, flag :=0][code!="",  flag := {rl <- rleid(code, year)-1; cummax(rl*(rl < 2)) }, id]` I get the same output

Comment: Assuming my understanding is correct, this still doesn't work as I would expect it. Try for example with `sample[3, c("year", "code") := list(2010, "zzz")]`. I might be wrong, which is why I asked OP to clarify

Answer (score 2):

A short solution with the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(samp)[, flag := 0][code!="", flag := 1*(rleid(code)-1 > 0), by = id]
```

Or:

```
setDT(samp)[, flag := 0][code!="", flag := 1*(code!=code[1] & code!=''), by = id][]
```

which gives the desired result:

```
> samp
    id year type code flag
 1:  1 2010    1  abc    0
 2:  1 2010    2  abc    0
 3:  1 2011    1         0
 4:  1 2011    2         0
 5:  1 2012    1  xyz    1
 6:  1 2012    2  xyz    1
 7:  2 2010    1         0
 8:  2 2010    2         0
 9:  2 2011    1  lmn    0
10:  2 2011    2         0
11:  2 2012    1  efg    1
12:  2 2012    2  efg    1
13:  3 2010    1  def    0
14:  3 2010    2  def    0
15:  3 2011    1  klm    1
16:  3 2011    2  klm    1
17:  3 2012    1  nop    1
18:  3 2012    2  nop    1
```

Or when the year is relevant as well:

```
setDT(samp)[, flag := 0][code!="", flag := 1*(rleid(code, year)-1 > 0), id]
```

---

A possible base R alternative:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- rle(x)$lengths
  1 * (rep(seq_along(x), times=x) - 1 > 0)
}

samp$flag <- 0
samp$flag[samp$code!=''] <- with(samp[samp$code!=''], ave(as.character(code), id, FUN = f))
```

---

NOTE: it is better not to give your object the same name as functions.

Used data:

```
samp <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each=6),
                   year = rep(2010:2012, 3, each=2),
                   type = (rep(1:2, 9)),
                   code = c("abc","abc","","","xyz","xyz", "","","lmn","","efg","efg","def","def","klm","klm","nop","nop"))
```

Comment: The output looks correct now but as commented under akruns answer, I think you're missing the year-column relevance

Comment: @docendodiscimus Updated, but I think OP has to make clear what (s)he exactly wants to do with the `year`-variable.